# Change color on hover for devicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement devicons into my website and I have done so successfully but, when I hover over them, the color doesnt change.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="devicons devicons-java"> </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.devicons {
    font-size: 150px;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.devicons.active:hover {
    color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

```css
.devicons {
    font-size: 150px;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.devicons.active:hover {
    color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="devicons devicons-java"> ABCD </div>
```

But this doesn't do anything on hover? I'm not sure what to do here now? Can someone give me an idea?

Answer (score 1):

remove .active.

So, it will be

```
.devicons:hover {
    color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

Your css is looking for .devicons that has a class of .active also. That's why it doesn't work. Hope it helps.

```css
.devicons {
    font-size: 150px;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.devicons:hover {
    color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="devicons devicons-java"> ABCD </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can slowly make it turn into orange? Instead of a blitz turn?

Comment: Add transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out; Don't forget to choose it as correct answer. So that if someone will look same problem like this. They can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is the hover and that effect you want on hover:

```
.button:hover {
   position: absolute;
   transition: 1.9s;
   color:orange;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the .active in .devicons.active:hover should do the trick